# Bounded L2 increments for an Ornstein Uhlenbeck type process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, levy-processes

Let $Z$ be an increasing Levy process (i.e. a subordinator). Let $\lambda>0$ and consider the Ornstein Uhlenbeck type SDE
$$
d V_t = - \lambda V_t dt + d Z_{\lambda t }
$$
where the integral can e.g. be defined using Lebesgue-Stieltjes.
The solution can e.g. be written 
$$
V_T = V_0 e^{-\lambda T} + \int_0^T e^{-\lambda(T-s)} dZ_{\lambda s}.
$$

Now let $t,s\geq 0$ can one then show that there exists $K>0$ such that 
$$
E[\lvert V_t - V_s \rvert^2 \wedge K] \leq K\lvert t-s \rvert?
$$
It is  an assumption I need satisfied for an application. I've tried to get the difference expressed as a difference of Levy processes to use the stationary, independent increments but I keep ending up with time intervals multiplied. Any ideas? What type of assumption is this anyway?

The [source](http://www.nber.org/papers/w18046) claims it is true "when the evolution of $V_t$ is given by a (multivariate) stochastic differential equation which is a common modeling approach for jump-diffusive asset returns displaying stochastic volatility. "

So a reference for this might suffice.

Comment: Is it of importance to you that the constants coincide or does it suffice to have an estimate of the form $$\mathbb{E}(|V_t-V_s|^2 \wedge K_1) \leq K_2 |t-s|$$ ....?

Comment: @saz The requirement is that they coincide. The assumption is on page 7.

Comment: @saz Given this does not seem to be possible, I am interested in the case with different constants now as well :)